# webhook telegram bot запросы в mysql

Tags: telegram-bot

```
$content = file_get_contents("php://input");

$update = json_decode($content, true);
```

Это вебхук бота телеграм.

```
if($update["message"]['text']=='start'):
  $chatID = $update["message"]["chat"]["id"];
  // compose reply
  $reply =  sendMessage();      
  // send reply
  $sendto =API_URL."sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatID."&text=".$reply;
  file_get_contents($sendto);
endif;
```

при команде старт шлет сообщение

```
 function sendMessage()
 {
  $message = urlencode("Для помощи нажмите /help. ".PHP_EOL."Для выбора  города: /cities");

 return $message;
 }
```

все работает.. Как только пытаюсь в эту команду добавить подключение к БД и запрос создать.. чтобы вытянуть например название города и отправить в сообщении название города. перестает работать..
Что-то упустил а что не понимаю..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$update["message"]['text'] == '/start'` команда приходит "как есть" включая слэш. По поводу коннекта к БД, убедитесь, что переменные используемые для него доступны внутри Вашей функции. Возможно что-то следует в неё передать в параметрах вызова.

Comment: пришел.. ответ запроса.. просто дольше.. :( не сделал поправку на то что скорость реакции будет не моментальная

Comment: Если дольше - это не нормально. Запросы/ответы ходят одинаково быстро. Вероятно у Вас всё же ошибка была. И только после устранения сервера телеграмма смогли достучаться до Вашего бота и получить от него ответ.